# Count the number of rows with non-zero values in two columns in MS-Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file with two columns. Let it be the ratings that different users have given for two movies. The movies represent the columns and the users represent the rows. I need to find the number of instances where a user has rated both the movies, in other words, how to find the number of rows where the two columns are both non-zeros.

```
[User]  [Star Wars (1977)]  [Star Wars (1983)]

755     1   5
5277    5   3
1577        
4388        3
1202    4   3
3823    2   4
5448        
5347    4   
4117    5   1
2765    4   2
```

The answer must be 6. I preferably am looking for something which gives 6 right away without any intermediate results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `COUNTIFS` function:

```
=COUNTIFS(B1:B10,">0",C1:C10,">0")
```

The `COUNTIFS` function applies criteria to cells across multiple ranges and counts the number of times all criteria are met. See [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has a function COUNTBLANK to test if a field is empty.

You could use this formula

```
= COUNTBLANK(B1) + COUNTBLANK(C1)
```

and if it returns 0 then you know there are no blanks.