# How to find number of rows with data count more than 3 in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Imagine we have a dataset in Google Sheets representing a grading book. Columns E, G, I, K, and M represent the score one has achieved for questions 1 to 5, and rows 5 to 64 are the student names. I want to see how many of the students have solved at least 3 questions; Here, by solving I mean that the student has gotten a full mark on that question (also the grade distribution can vary; for example, question 1 has 10 points while the other have 25 points).
Note that one thing that popped into my mind was to create a new column and store the number of solved questions for each student there (and then iterate over them and see how many of them are >= 3); Is there a way to satisfy the problem without creating or using new row/columns?

I didn't find anything proper that had to deal with rows and also keeping track of the cell count in those rows. One approach is to use Inclusion–exclusion principle with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38047665/count-the-number-of-rows-with-non-zero-values-in-two-columns-in-ms-excel) here. It'd basically be something like
`COUNTIFS(E5:E64,E4,G5:G64,G4,I5:I64,I4) + COUNTIFS(E5:E64,E4,G5:G64,G4,K5:K64,K4) + COUNTIFS(E5:E64,E4,G5:G64,G4,M5:M64,M4) + COUNTIFS(E5:E64,E4,I5:I64,I4,K5:K64,K4) + COUNTIFS(E5:E64,E4,I5:I64,I4,M5:M64,M4) + COUNTIFS(E5:E64,E4,K5:K64,K4,M5:M64,M4) + COUNTIFS(G5:G64,G4,I5:I64,I4,K5:K64,K4) + COUNTIFS(G5:G64,G4,I5:I64,I4,M5:M64,M4) + COUNTIFS(G5:G64,G4,K5:K64,K4,M5:M64,M4) + COUNTIFS(I5:I64,I4,K5:K64,K4,M5:M64,M4) - (COUNTIFS(E5:E64,E4,G5:G64,G4,I5:I64,I4,K5:K64,K4) + COUNTIFS(E5:E64,E4,G5:G64,G4,I5:I64,I4,M5:M64,M4) + COUNTIFS(E5:E64,E4,G5:G64,G4,K5:K64,K4,M5:M64,M4) + COUNTIFS(E5:E64,E4,I5:I64,I4,K5:K64,K4,M5:M64,M4) + COUNTIFS(G5:G64,G4,I5:I64,I4,K5:K64,K4,M5:M64,M4) - COUNTIFS(E5:E64,E4,G5:G64,G4,I5:I64,I4,K5:K64,K4,M5:M64,M4))`

this [link](https://exceljet.net/formulas/count-rows-that-contain-specific-values) was the closest I got.
I think using matrices and multiplying them could be the solution. However, I'm not very good at that!
I'd appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Update: here is a table to better understand this problem. The formula should return 2 (w and z both are satisfiable).

| Student Name | Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3 | Question 4 | Question 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mr. x | 10 | 14 | 17 | 8 | 25 |
| Mr. y | 8 | 25 | 25 | 14 | 19 |
| Mr. w | 10 | 25 | 17 | 8 | 25 |
| Mr. z | 10 | 14 | 25 | 25 | 25 |

Comment: Which version of Excel?  That will matter a lot on a problem like this, as Excel O365 opens up a lot of possibilities.  And am I correct in understanding that by “full mark” you mean any score > 0?

Comment: Show few input data and your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should cover it:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(((E5:E64=E4)+(G5:G64=G4)+(I5:I64=I4)+(K5:K64=K4)+(M5:M64=M4))>=3))
```

Comment: Yup! worked like a charm. Thank you very much! Would you mind explaining a bit about what you did there?

Comment: You can easily see what is happening by selecting each part of the formula and using `F9` to evaluate it. If you select `E4:E64=E4` and press `F9` you will see trues and falses. To convert them to ones and zeroes you can use `--` on the expression. If you sum up those five arrays and add `>=3` you will again get trues and falses so again you need to use `--` to get ones and zeroes. Finally, you have to wrap it into `SUMPRODUCT` to get the count. While I was figuring this out, I used in `O5` the following formula `=SUMPRODUCT(--(E5=E$4)+--(G5=G$4)+--(I5=I$4)+--(K5=K$4)+--(M5=M$4))`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 You can dispense with all the `--` operations.  Excel typecasts TRUE/FALSE in to binary 1s and 0s whenever a mathematical operation is performed.  Doesn’t just have to be the `-` operator, a `+` operation causes it as well.  Since you applied addition to all your terms, they will have already been forced into a binary recast.  Thus:  `=SUMPRODUCT(((E5:E64=E4)+(G5:G64=G4)+(I5:I64=I4)+(K5:K64=K4)+(M5:M64=M4))>=3)` should work.

Comment: @Max R: Except that it doesn't but you are right. Here is the correct correction: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(((E5:E64=E4)+(G5:G64=G4)+(I5:I64=I4)+(K5:K64=K4)+(M5:M64=M4))>=3))` which you probably meant in the first place. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @VBasic2008 You are correct, I did overlook that the `>=3` term will in fact resolve to true/false.

Comment: @VBasic2008 One more thing, you aren’t actually “sumproduct-ing” anything.  I got the same result by replacing `sumproduct()` simply with `sum()`.  You’re just summing the result array of 1s and 0s.  So the corrected correct correction would really be `=SUM(--(((E5:E64=E4)+(G5:G64=G4)+(I5:I64=I4)+(K5:K64=K4)+(M5:M64=M4))>=3))`  :)

Comment: Well, I guess you have *Office 365*. The older versions require an array formula for `SUM` to work. That's why I used `SUMPRODUCT`. I guess one could say that I'm *sumproducting* myself out of an array formula.